# PhantomJS 2 returns error 9 "the background request is not currently allowed due to platform policy"

Tags: phantomjs, qt5

I use PhantomJS 1.9 with rasterise.js on my webapp.

I'm testing PhantomJS 2.0 locally on my Mac (10.10.5)

```
$cmd = "phantomjs rasterize.js http://example.com/pdf doc.pdf 29.7cm*21cm"
$proc=proc_open($cmd,array(0=>array('pipe','r'),1=>array('pipe','w'),2=>array('pipe','w')),$pipes);
$stdout=stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[1]);
$stderr=stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
fclose($pipes[2]);
$rtn=proc_close($proc);
print_r( array('stdout'=>$stdout,'stderr'=>$stderr,'return'=>$rtn));
```

And it returns :

```
Array ( [stdout] => [stderr] => [return] => 9 )
```

According to http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html, the "9" error corresponds to

> QNetworkReply::BackgroundRequestNotAllowedError   9   the background request is not currently allowed due to platform policy.

If I switch back to PhantomJS 1.9.2, it works fine.

Any clue ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: No, it's the code provided in the example folder of PhantomJS : https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js  cf the doc : http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html

Comment: It was just a typo in my example code. But my actual code is correct, as it works when I use PhantomJS 1.9